# C# library for Lego Mindstorm NXT

Tags: c#, .net, lego-mindstorms, nxt

Is there C# (.NET) library for Lego Mindstorm NXT, which is up-to-date?

**NXT.NET for LEGO Mindstorms**

- last update 18.04.2008
- http://nxtnet.codeplex.com/

**MindSqualls**

- last update 05.06.2007
- http://www.mindsqualls.net/

**Lego .NET**

- last update 07.04.2005
- http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/research/lego.NET/weblog/

I know, there is MS Robotic studio, but my question is not about that.

Comment: What makes you think these releases are not up to date?

Comment: nobugz: For example, Lego Mindstorms NXT 2.0 was released on August 5 2009. Or new sensors was released.

Comment: For those stumbling upon this closed question, another option has presented itself .. look to http://www.monobrick.dk/software/ev3firmware/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, There is no source code available for [NXT.NET for LEGO Mindstorms](http://nxtnet.codeplex.com/) despite the project being hosted on codeplex.  The library is not really complete yet - and it would seem that development has stalled.

The [MindSqualls library](http://www.mindsqualls.net/) has not been updated recently, but still appears fairly complete and usable.  Some recent [modifications are available elsewhere](http://nxtcodecollection.codeplex.com/).

You've said you aren't interested in [MS Robotics Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/robotics/default.aspx) but that works well with Lego NXT.  Personally, I would find it had to justify using something else other than "for the challenge" of doing so.

Comment: I think MS Robotics Studio requires a live bluetooth connection to the hosting PC that runs the "AI" code.  This means that the NXT creation is being remote controlled and is not truly autonomous.  This is in contract to NQC and the Java VMs that are actually running on the brick itself.  However, I would love to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 9):

I made the source code for the NXT.NET library available on CodePlex, but unfortunately it is true that the development of the library has stalled :(

You can find the source code here for download:
http://nxtnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/12686

Answer (score 6):

[The microsoft robotics SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/robotics/default.aspx) (for .net) is compatible with mindstorms.

Answer (score 3):

I used AForge.NET for my project. (http://www.aforgenet.com/)

The last update was February 23, 2012.

It makes controlling the Lego Mindstorm NXT very easy.
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/lego_robotics.html#nxt

Comment: There has been a new update on July 17, 2013 to Version 2.2.5. http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/release_notes/2.2.5.html

Answer (score 1):

You can just send down real-time / Direct commands to the NXT in its native format.  You don't necessarily need the NXT library.

It sounds like you are using the library, however it can be easily augmented by just sending a command to the com port that the NXT is connected up with.  Here is a great tutorial on the NXT direct commands:

http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/Programming-LEGO-NXT-Mindstorms/92.html

-Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use MRDS, and could not do it. The whole system with services and many twists in most cases only complicates everything.
Now I try to understand [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/lego_robotics.html#nxt) and [MindSqualls](http://www.mindsqualls.net/), until they look much better.