# MonobrickFirmware library - What do the parameters rampUpSteps, constantSpeedSteps and rampDownSteps mean?

Tags: c#, lego-mindstorms

[image]

I'm using the MonoBrickFirmware library, but there's little to no documentation about it on the internet, and I need to get one of the motors working that is connected with the arms of my robot through cogs. What do the parameters "**rampUpSteps**", "**constantSpeedSteps**" and "**rampDownSteps**" mean?

I've tried filling in a power value of 100, and use random values for rampUpSteps, constantSpeedSteps and rampDownSteps, and it turns out that if all values are 0 the motor does not move, but if one of the values is greater than 0 the motor starts moving.

Edit: I'm using the EV3 brick.

Comment: Without knowing anything about this product, just trying to decipher the English, I'd guess "ramp up steps" would mean the number of steps the motor performs first slowly and then a bit faster and faster, until it reaches "crusing speed". "constant speed steps" would then be the number of steps the motor is to run at standard speed. Use of the word "steps" probably implies the motor is a "stepping motor" - common for electric motors used to control things. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor

Comment: @RenniePet Thanks for thinking with me. My teacher told me I'm dealing with a Servo motor. Does that make sense to u with these parameters?

Comment: I really don't know anything about this, sorry - I just commented because your question is tagged C# and you hadn't gotten any answers. Have you seen this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408927/c-sharp-library-for-lego-mindstorm-nxt ?

Comment: That said, I find your project interesting. More fun than what I'm working on! Did a bit of surfing and found this: http://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Interactive-Servo-Motor-9842?fromListing=listing So your teacher is probably right that it is a servo motor. But it says "The Servo Motor has a built-in rotation sensor that measures speed and distance, and reports back to the NXT Intelligent Brick. This allows for precise steps and complete motor control within one degree of accuracy!" So I take this to mean that although it is a servo motor the electronics make the interface simulate a stepper motor.

Comment: And this: http://www.programmingforums.org/post187648.html "Incidentally, motor control, even with a stepper or servo, is not trivial. Electronics can provide stimuli much faster than the motor can react. ..." Try googling things like "mindstorms c# motor control". Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the PowerProfile if you don't understand its purpose?

In any case, here's what the steps mean. Let's take speed for example and couch this in terms of driving a car with a passenger. We're going to accelerate from 0mph to 60mph. Passenger is grandma. How do you accelerate? Slowly. You might take 10s to go from 0 to 60mph.

In the case of your controller, changing speed is digital, it happens at discrete intervals. So, say each interval (or step is 1s long). Then you'd be increasing speed by 6mph in every step. So, the steps pretty much control acceleration - how fast a transition from one speed to another takes place.

As you can see, in my example, the speed increment is constant in every step. But, you are not limited to that. So the power profile gives you a bit more control. So instead, you might do something like:

step 0: Speed at 0

step 1: Speed + 6mph, speed at 6mph

step 2: Speed + 12mph, speed at 18mph

step 3: Speed + 18mph, speed at 36mph

step 4: Speed + 18mph, speed at 54mph

step 5: Speed + 5.9mph, speed at 59.9mph

step 6: Speed + 0.5mph, speed at 60mph

So as you can see, you went from 0 to 60 in the same number of steps, yet the way you got there was different. Specifying the path you take is what's captured in a "profile".

Answer (score 0):

You might find the official documentation helpfull. http://www.monobrick.dk/MonoBrickFirmwareDocumentation/class_mono_brick_firmware_1_1_movement_1_1_motor.html#a2249968caaaf995fd63cab066113127c

/Anders (Creator of MonoBrick)

Comment: Hi, I've checked the docs before. It doesn't make much sense to me. What's a "speed profile"? And what do the 3 step parameters mean?